# sessionFactory only called once in applicationContext-security.xml?

Tags: spring, hibernate, security, authentication

An issue I'm unsure of atm, I have hibernate handling my logins through a user table. If this table is manipulated whilst the app is running, no change takes place on the login side of things (however they do on tables, I'm using ZK for that and can see the changes correctly).
So if I log in with:
admin password

Then change the password to newpassword

I have to clean & build the app, then run it before the change takes place for the login.
So in other words I think it only checks the user table data once, keeps it somewhere?

Anyway code I think might help:

snippet of applicationContext-security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="sesFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="configLocation">
        <beans:value>classpath:\hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDAO" class="login.UserLoginDAOImpl">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sesFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userService" class="login.UserLoginService">
    <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

<authentication-manager>
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <!--<password-encoder hash="sha" />-->
     </authentication-provider>      
</authentication-manager>
```

hibernation.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>


     <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>



    <mapping class="contacts.Contacts" />
    <mapping class="login.Users" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

UserLoginDaoImpl:

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
  package login;


import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

/**
 * The Class UserLoginDAOImpl
 */
public class UserLoginDAOImpl implements UserLoginDAO {

/** The hibernate template. */
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

/**
 * Sets the session factory.
 * 
 * @param sessionFactory
 *            the new session factory
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

@Override
public Users loadUserByName(String name) {
    if (name != null && !name.equals("")) {

        List<Users> usr = hibernateTemplate
                .find("from Users where username ='" + name + "'");
                        System.out.println(usr.get(0));
        if (usr.size() == 1) {
            return usr.get(0);
        } else {
                        System.out.println("USER SIZE IS INCORRECT");
            return null;

        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your UserLoginDAOImpl source code? And UserLoginService too.

Comment: Do you have `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in your `web.xml`? How can Hibernate recognize that your session shall be closed?

Comment: The code is largely unchanged from this http://arielsweb.com/?p=115

Comment: As for OpenSessioninViewFilter, I just tried that and it didn't work. Along with trying out proxied transactionManager (doesn't work).
Similar to this: http://sourabhissourabh.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/what-is-opensessioninviewfilter-and-how.html

Comment: What is the source code of Users class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert in Hibernate, but I think that

`<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>`

line is unnecessary and affects the behavior of transaction manager: See [spring, hibernate and declarative transaction implementation: there is no active transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138663/spring-hibernate-and-declarative-transaction-implementation-there-is-no-active)

<sub>P.S. Spring manages transactions via AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and possibly something interesting happens inside your UserLoginDAOImpl and UserLoginService classes.</sub>

Comment: Without it I get: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! :(

Comment: Please add  the **actual** UserLoginDAOImpl source code to your question. Anyway you can refactor it to use [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) I hope :) It's not clear how transcations are opened and closed in your configuration.

Comment: Updated the answer with it, I've tried using the typical hibernateUtil class - opening a session, beginning a transaction then commit. The rest of my application works perfectly fine with updates from hibernateUtil - however specifically the login doesn't.

Comment: what is the stack trace of  No CurrentSessionContext configured? do you get it from UserLoginDAOImpl or from somewhere else?

Comment: Aha! few changes to sessionFactory stuff, realised hibernateTemplate uses currentsession and not openSession. So I just made a new session/opened it/begintransaction/commit

Thanks for the replies guys! :) (can't answer my own Q atm, account is ~8hrs old)