# Hibernate: Could not register synchronization

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, websphere

While using spring + hibenate alongwith Websphere server I am getting this exeption

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Could not register synchronization
```

Hibernate properties in spring config file is

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/jndiName</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</prop>

    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.aggressive_release">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>  
</props>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138663/spring-hibernate-and-declarative-transaction-implementation-there-is-no-active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere itself handles all pooling and cache level for its Data sources. All JDBC related configurations can be performed through WebSphere administrative console. So writing

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/jndiName</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</prop>
</props>
```

is sufficient in Spring.