# Normal Spring + Hibernate Transaction behaviour?

Tags: hibernate, transactions, aop, spring-transactions

I've got my Spring + Hibernate project configured to be transactional using Spring AOP.

When I check in the DAO method with `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` it says true.
I'm calling two DAO methods from my service class and in the second DAO method, I do `'devide by zero'` intentionally to throw an error and see if the two method rollback. 
Currently the first one seems to insert a new record just fine. Shouldn't the first method
 rollback ? 

**Update**
You can refer to my previous question but I think this may be too lengthy.
[Transaction Management in Spring 3.x and Hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828579/transaction-management-in-spring-3-x-and-hibernate-4)

To sum the question (as much as I can), 
I have one service class method that calls two methods from a DAO class.
That service class is being called from a spring mvc controller and its delegater.

I've got my aop:config as follows

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:pointcut id="transactionalServiceOperation" expression="execution(* kr.co.sgis.services.web.cooingbee.Crudable.*(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionalServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

My interface Crudable looks like this

```
public interface Crudable {

    public int delete(CooingbeeFetchable bean);
    public int save(CooingbeeFetchable bean);
    public int update(CooingbeeFetchable bean);
    public Set<CooingbeeFetchable> list(CooingbeeFetchable bean);
    public CooingbeeFetchable get(int id);
    public int count(CooingbeeFetchable bean);
    public int save2(CooingbeeFetchable bean);
}
```

*Both* DAO and Service class implement Cruadable interface. Now I think maybe that's the 
reason it's not working as I expected ?
Hope I gave you enough information without being too lengthy : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out finally.
Read this.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

The document says you need to throw an exception for Spring to know that something's wrong 
with a DAO method so that it could rollback. Previously my DAO methods didn't throw any exceptions, instead they handled exceptions by themselves by surrounding the method body in a
try-catch block.

also, you need to configure your aop:config tag like this.

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:pointcut id="transactionalServiceOperation" expression="execution(* kr.co.sgis.services.web.cooingbee.Crudable.*(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionalServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

I hope this helps ! : )
cheers

Answer (score 0):

If both methods are transactional, then naturally the second one's failing won't affect the first one. If you think both methods are part of a single (correct) transaction, then you're mistaken either about that or about the fact that it seemed to partially commit. You'd need to provide a lot more information to get a good answer as to why one or the other is true.